# MariaDB service fails to start with InnoDB Space id error

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb, mysqld

I've been running MariaDB on a Raspberry Pi 4 (Raspbian 10 / buster) as the database server for my Webtrees and Owncloud sites. Recently, I noticed that the server wasn't looking right, and after a reboot, I can see that the MariaDB service is failing to start.

Contents of /var/log/mysql/error.log:

```
2021-03-26 14:45:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2021-03-26 14:45:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2021-03-26 14:45:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-03-26 14:45:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-03-26 14:45:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-03-26 14:45:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2021-03-26 14:45:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Disabling background log and ibuf IO write threads.
2021-03-26 14:45:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2021-03-26 14:45:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-03-26 14:45:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: innodb_force_recovery=6 skips redo log apply
2021-03-26 14:45:06 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Space id and page no stored in the page, read in are [page id: space=0, page number=399], should be [page id: space=0, page number=394]
210326 14:45:06 [ERROR] mysqld got signal 11 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.

To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs

We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

Server version: 10.3.27-MariaDB-0+deb10u1
key_buffer_size=134217728
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=153
thread_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 466214 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0x0 thread_stack 0x49000
The manual page at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/how-to-produce-a-full-stack-trace-for-mysqld/ contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
Writing a core file...
Working directory at /var/lib/mysql
Resource Limits:
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units
Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds
Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max stack size            8388608              unlimited            bytes
Max core file size        0                    unlimited            bytes
Max resident set          unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max processes             12860                12860                processes
Max open files            16384                16384                files
Max locked memory         65536                65536                bytes
Max address space         unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks
Max pending signals       12860                12860                signals
Max msgqueue size         819200               819200               bytes
Max nice priority         0                    0
Max realtime priority     0                    0
Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us
Core pattern: core
```

Here's the terminal output from trying to start fro the terminal:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart mariadb.service
Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Libraries:

```
 $ ldd /usr/sbin/mysqld
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0xbefe7000)
        /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-${PLATFORM}.so => /usr/lib/arm-li                      nux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-v7l.so (0xb562e000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0 (0xb5604000)
        liblz4.so.1 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/liblz4.so.1 (0xb55d8000)
        libsnappy.so.1 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libsnappy.so.1 (0xb55c100                      0)
        libaio.so.1 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libaio.so.1 (0xb55af000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libz.so.1 (0xb5584000)
        libpcre.so.3 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpcre.so.3 (0xb550d000)
        libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcrypt.so.1 (0xb54cd000)
        libsystemd.so.0 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libsystemd.so.0 (0xb5430000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl.so.2 (0xb541d000)
        libatomic.so.1 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libatomic.so.1 (0xb540400                      0)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb52bd00                      0)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6 (0xb523b000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0xb50ed000)
        /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0xb6ed4000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb50c0000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt.so.1 (0xb50a9000)
        liblzma.so.5 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/liblzma.so.5 (0xb5078000)
        libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcrypt.so.20 (0xb4f9e000)
        libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgpg-error.so.0 (0xb4f74                      000)
```

Googling hasn't turned up too much, though I've tried

```
innodb_force_recovery = 1 (and all the way up to 6!)
innodb_purge_threads=0
```

In /etc/mysql/my.cnf, which didn't seem to change anything.

Any thoughts before I attempt to restore from backup?

Comment: Only that the messages don't seem to be pointing to a problem with the database - which is probably what you'd be restoring.  Rather software, memory or configuration.   Any change or upgrade before you noticed the problem?

Comment: No changes or upgrades, I'm afraid. I have no errors showing fsck, I'll have a look running a memory test later.

Comment: Someone managed to solve this problem using mysqlcheck -o.  Check the libraries used by mysqld :  "ldd /usr/sbin/mysqld"

Comment: mysqlcheck doesn't seem to work, because I can't get the server running at all.:

```
$ mysqlcheck -o -A
mysqlcheck: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket                       '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) when trying to connect
```
I'll add the ldd output to the main question, nothing obvious wrong there.
It might be that I've missed something, of course, I'm a noob at this. Your input appreciated.

Comment: why do you have a recovery at all. disable it and see what error you get and check for solutions

Comment: If you move the database data folder to a safe place (rename it, eg), does that allow you to start the database daemon?  That would prove me wrong, and show that the problem is within the data.

Comment: Hi @nbk. I started without recovery, of course. The InnoDB: Space id error message is there with or without recovery.

Comment: @Gerard: I moved /var/lib/mysql to /var/lib/mysqlOLD, restarted, and the error persists. I guess you were right! Any suggestions on what to try next?

Comment: I've only got RPi2 and 3, moreover I'm on Devuan, so we can't compare the libraries or installation.  In your case, if you're 100% sure you have the database in a secure location, I would go for a fresh install of the OS, and see if mysqld runs, then take your current config with that, test mysqld again.  If it still works, put the data back and try again.

Comment: Fair enough. I’ll give that a go. Thanks very much for your input.

Comment: This might be related to this hard to reproduce [MariaDB bug MDEV-21109](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-21109). If you can provide a history of what happened before you discovered this error message it may give the developers enough of an hint to identify the problem. A description of large, aborted, or abnormal InnoDB table changes, or configuration changes would be most appreciated on the fore-mentioned bug report.

Comment: @Charlie  Any news?

Comment: I rebuilt from a backup sql that I had from a while ago, so it's working again now. I uninstalled (purged) mariadb*, mysql* and autoremoved everything, then reinstalled mariadb-server. I could then set up the database server OK. I tried copying the /var/lib/mysql folder back into place, and ended up with the same InnoDB errors as before. So I really don't know what wen on! I promise to do better backups next time... Thanks again for your input.

Comment: @danblack I'm afraid I've already rebuilt everything before seeing your comment. Looking at the bug, though, I'm not sure it's the same. Also, there were no particular or unusual changes to the databases, so I don't think I would have been able to help much.